# What's the point of 500GB cloud storage on a 32GB SSD laptop?

Tags: cloud-storage

I have recently bought asus x205ta laptop with 32GB mSSD drive. It comes with 500GB asus web storage and ms cloud which is 1TB but I don't understand the point of having so much cloud storage when all you can keep is 20GB at max? When I put my files into the asus webstorage sync folder the files get synced but they still take space so what's the point of all this cloud storage?

Comment: First of all: Your data isnt lost if your hardware fails or the laptop gets stolen. Second: As long as you have Internet access you can tell the PC to handle the cloud like additional hardware so you can write and read data without using your own hardware

Comment: I agree with the first, but how do I tell the PC to handle the cloud as additional hardware when all it does is synchronizing files on SSD with the cloud?

Comment: I sadly dont have any experience with the asus cloud but maybe this helps you: https://www.asuswebstorage.com/navigate/downloads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question states you already have discovered the *Cloud Sync* which is pretty useful to sync data between multiple computers.

You are searching the *Asus remote drive* which basically is an external harddrive hosted by Asus where you can put data similar to a harddrive but with the difference that you need Internet access and that the data isn't stored on hardware you own. This is not as fast as an SSD.

Asus provides downloads for Windows and Linux on their website:
https://www.asuswebstorage.com/navigate/downloads/